# Shared clipboard between multiple Macbooks

Tags: macbook-pro, copy-paste

I have a Macbook Air (2017) and Macbook Pro (early 2015). As a developer, I want to do my development on Pro and browsing, emails and other stuff on my Air at the same time. This requires some copy-paste between the machines.

I was looking at the Universal Clipboard feature. I have followed all the steps in [this article](https://www.imore.com/how-use-universal-clipboard-copy-file-one-mac-and-paste-it-another-macos-high-sierra) but its not working. I am not sure if this is Mac to iOS only feature.

I am running macOS Mojave (10.14.4) on both machines. Please let me know if you require any additional information.

P.S. In the meantime I am using Notes as a shared clipboard.

Comment: Is screen sharing or ssh a viable solution in your eyes? I use those for this.

Comment: Have you set up the Macs according to: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT209460 ?

Comment: @bmike Sorry, I am not inclined to use screen sharing or ssh. For my use case, using Notes as a shared clipboard is a much better solution. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

If you are signed into the same iCloud account and have the Continuity features turned on you should be able to copy and paste between machines.

- [macOS Sierra: Copy and paste across devices](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH25168)

> With Universal Clipboard, you can copy text, images, photos, and videos on one Apple device and then paste the content on another Apple device.

> Note: To use Universal Clipboard, your devices must meet Continuity system requirements. They must also have Wi-Fi, Bluetooth, and Handoff turned on in System Preferences (on your Mac) and in Settings (on your iOS devices). You must be signed in to iCloud using the same Apple ID on all your devices.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different SE! Good answer +1. I've wanted to do this once or twice, and didn't even bother to research it because I thought, "Nah - they won't do that." :)

Comment: I went through the support link in the answer before asking the question. It still doesn't work. I was wondering if someone else is able to get it working between two Macs.

Comment: I am able to copy an paste across Macs.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not perfect because you always need to go through an app, but it looks like [CloudClip](https://www.thinkbitz.com/cloudclip/) or [Nice Clipboard](https://www.getniceapps.com/nice-clipboard) might fit your needs.

Update: Actually I find myself often sending iMessages to myself for that.